# POSTFIX Not delivering mail to one box

Tags: postfix

One of my users has been experiencing a weird problem.
He is on a distribution list and does not receive any of these emails.

His mailbox is spelled correctly in the mail headers, and other employees on this list receive the email correctly.

Checking the MessageID in /var/log/maillog (Centos 6.5) shows that the mail is delivered to 3 people correctly but not this particular user.

**From Mail Header**

```
From: "Vendor Guy" <vendor@company.ca>
To: 1 <1@us.com>,
    2 <2@us.com>,
    4 <4@us.com>, <---- This mailbox does not get the mail delivered
    3 <3@us.com>
```

Excerpt from maillog (POSTFIX transaction)

```
Feb  9 09:16:57 localhost postfix/pickup[11671]: B6EA8A19CC: uid=678 from=<vendor@company.ca>
Feb  9 09:16:57 localhost postfix/cleanup[11864]: B6EA8A19CC: message-id=<69FF169A9DA89141B06AD81F2B9A0A16049AC6B834@MBX09.company.ca>
Feb  9 09:16:57 localhost postfix/qmgr[16938]: B6EA8A19CC: from=<vendor@company.ca>, size=11954, nrcpt=3 (queue active)
Feb  9 09:16:57 localhost postfix/local[11869]: B6EA8A19CC: to=<1@us.com>, relay=local, delay=0.04, delays=0.02/0/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Feb  9 09:16:57 localhost postfix/local[11972]: B6EA8A19CC: to=<2@us.com>, relay=local, delay=0.04, delays=0.02/0/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Feb  9 09:16:57 localhost postfix/local[11987]: B6EA8A19CC: to=<3@us.com>, relay=local, delay=0.05, delays=0.02/0.01/0/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Feb  9 09:16:57 localhost postfix/qmgr[16938]: B6EA8A19CC: removed
```

From the log you can see that postfix only recognizes 3 recipients when there should be 4.

I am at a bit of a loss as to why this is happening to just 1 company that sends this particular person email.

I have looked over all of the log files and come up with nothing...

Comment: What process (`pid 678`) is dropping this mail to postfix? Is it properly adding `4@us.com` recipient along with other recipients? Adding data `To` doesn't mean it added an `RCPT TO` for that recipient?

Comment: The TO statements come from the message source recorded by ThunderBird. I dont know any way to grab the rcpt to line, how would I find that out? It is adding 4 properly. It skips 3.

Comment: The process is spam assassin.

Answer (score 2):

LuckyBurger - You mention that spam assasin is the process dropping the mail. Not familiar with your entire email environment, but if you have an environment that allows individualized spam settings, I would check the user_prefs file for 4@us.com - if nothing obvious stands out, I would whitelist vendor@company.ca there and try a test message again. If nothing along those lines work, it would be helpful if you could check back in here and let us know how the logs & headers look during the test messages.